# In ListviewAdapter I dont know why getview() function not call

Tags: java, android, android-listview

i want know why getview() function is not call
maybe override is wrong?
i want make custom listlayout
what's wrong in listviewadapter?

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Word> items;

public ListViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Word> items) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.items = items;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return items.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wordlist_layout, viewGroup, false);
    }
    TextView wordview1 = view.findViewById(R.id.wordView1);        
    System.out.println("wordlist layout = " + items.get(i).w1);
    wordview1.setText(items.get(i).w1);
   
    return view;
}
```

// this is my Main activity code

```
private ArrayList<Word> items;
private ListViewAdapter listviewadapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.submit_Button);        


    btn.setOnClickListener(view -> {           

        ListView word_listview = findViewById(R.id.Wordle_Word_List);
        items = new ArrayList<Word>();
 
        items.add(new Word('a'));
        listviewadapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items);
        word_listview.setAdapter(listviewadapter);


    });
}
```

i dont know what is missing in my code
In ListviewAdapter I dont know why getview() function not call

Comment: Code seems fine . How r you So sure that its not getting called ? Add a break point on `getView` and debug it . Or put a Log inside `getView`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the condition in its body, not the whole function. There is no need to check if it is null or not. you can simply inflate the view as mentioned in this [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/155-android-listview-tutorial-with-kotlin):

```
 @Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wordlist_layout, viewGroup, false);
    TextView wordview1 = view.findViewById(R.id.wordView1);
    System.out.println("wordlist layout = " + items.get(i).w1);
    wordview1.setText(items.get(i).w1);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.wordlist_layout, viewGroup, false);

    TextView wordview1  = view.findViewById(R.id.wordView1);
    wordview1.setText(items.get(i).w1);

    return view;
}
```